# Flutter/Dart: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch return the incorrect time

Tags: date, dart, flutter, epoch

DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch() method will return the DateTime since 1970-1-1 0:0:0.0 + milliseconds

Actually, if we pass 1 milliseconds, it will return 1970-1-1 8:0:0.1, this confused me.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `isUtc: true`.  If you don't, the `DateTime` will be based on your local time zone.  From the [`DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html):

> If `isUtc` is false then the date is in the local time zone.